# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee84eaf60) for my CLLocationManager()

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager, exc-bad-access

I have no idea why this started or how to solve it.  The error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee84eaf60) occurs on my line:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

I declared it in my class above viewDidLoad().  I've run this simulator a ton of times without this problem, and it randomly popped up now.  I checked to make sure it wasn't the most recent code I added by running it again without said code, and the error persists.  Just in case you think of this, it's not that my default location is set to none, I've had that error before and fixed it.  Here are all the parts of my code where my locationManager is used:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

then:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    
    tapToAddJumpSpotLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

then:

```
@IBAction func allowLocationButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {

    // Case when authorization not determined.
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    // Case when authorization granted.
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Access Granted", message: "We already have access to your location.  If you want to change this, go to your settings app, and change our location access.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okayAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // Case when authorization denied or restricted.
    case .restricted, .denied:
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Access Disabled", message: "We need access to your location in order to provide you with cliff jumping spots.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default) { (action) in
            if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(openAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // Default (Apple has possible future cases to be added to CLAuthorizationStatus).
    @unknown default:
        return
    }
}
```

finally:

```
//MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    if let error = error as? CLError, error.code == .denied {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print(error)
        return
    }
    
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let lastLocation = locations.last!
    mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude = lastLocation.coordinate.latitude
    mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude = lastLocation.coordinate.longitude
}
```

}

I have no idea what is causing this so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you show the crashed thread...in case it has any hints?  ("bt" in the debug window.)

Comment: @PhillipMills not exactly sure what you mean by "bt", but my debug window has this on the left: self Jumper.ViewController 0x0000618000378480
UIKit.UIViewController UIViewController 
mapView MKMapView? nil none
tapToAddJumpSpotLabel UILabel? nil none
locationManager CLLocationManager 0x0000000000000000
ObjectiveC.NSObject NSObject 
jumpSpotCreatorController Jumper.JumpSpotCreatorController 0x0000000000000000
userIsAllowedToAddAnnotation Bool false                    AND on the right just (11db)

Comment: I mean, when it crashes, type "bt" at the (lldb) prompt.

Comment: @PhillipMills ok, it gave me a ton of lines, here's the beggining: thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee244fb70)
    frame #0: 0x000000010d11ab4a libclang_rt.asan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`__sanitizer_mz_malloc + 58
    frame #1: 0x00007fff51b732a3 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_zone_malloc + 104
    frame #2: 0x00007fff23de0d50 CoreFoundation`__CFStringChangeSizeMultiple + 848
    frame #3: 0x00007fff23dda33e CoreFoundation`__CFStringAppendBytes + 654
    not sure how much that helps but it's literally thousands of lines

Comment: Are there lines that mention something in your code?  Those ones say something went wrong with memory allocation while working with a string...which isn't very specific.

Comment: @PhillipMills not that I can see, after that most of the lines resemble stuff like this: .init(nibNameOrNil=nil, nibBundleOrNil=nil)   ..  I read on other SO posts that this is a memory error, and my code has run perfectly with these lines before, which is why this is so strange... Unless I'm mistaken, this error didn't seem to be cause by any of my code

Comment: Well, if it's happening during nib loading, it could be something odd in a storyboard (or xib file).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219925/discussion-between-derek-and-phillip-mills).

Comment: @PhillipMills I added like 5 new outlets recently, could it be those?
should i try commenting them out?
I appreciate your help btw

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some  further digging I feel stupid.  Simply an old object initialization of one class in another, and vice versa, causing an infinite loop.  Good thing is one of them was old and I just forgot to delete it, so there ya go!